# Smart Makefile: way scan directory tree and compile .c files

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I am doing a project which is growing pretty fast, but my Makefile has a strong dependence on filenames.

my directory tree:
Makefile
source
source/phase2
source/include

this directory are create from Makefile:
exec_phase2.test
source/build

this is part of my Makefile

```
# Project path
PH2 = source
SRC_PH2 = $(PH2)/phase2
INCL_PH2 = $(PH2)/include
EXEC_PH2 = exec_phase2.test
BUILD_PH2 = $(PH2)/build

# Header file path
HEAD_PH2 = $(INCL_PH2)/const.h $(INCL_PH2)/listx.h $(INCL_PH2)/mikabooq.h

# Object files path
OBJECTS_PH2 = $(BUILD_PH2)/main.o $(BUILD_PH2)/mikabooq.o $(BUILD_PH2)/testP.o


all: mikaboo

mikaboo: phase2.test

phase2.test: clean buildOutDir coreFile

buildOutDir: 
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_PH2)
    mkdir -p $(EXEC_PH2)

coreFile: $(EXEC_PH2)/main.elf
    $(ELF) $(ELFFLAG) $<

$(EXEC_PH2)/main.elf: $(OBJECTS_PH2)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAG) $(LINKER_UARM_PH2)

$(BUILD_PH2)/main.o: $(SRC_PH2)/main.c $(BUILD_PH2)/mikabooq.o $(HEAD_PH2)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $@ $<

$(BUILD_PH2)/mikabooq.o: $(SRC_PH2)/mikabooq.c $(HEAD_PH2)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $@ $<

$(BUILD_PH2)/testP.o: $(SRC_PH2)/testP.c $(HEAD_PH2) $(HEAD_KER)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_PH2) $(EXEC_PH2)
```

I would like automatize the search of sources and header file:
I see these two command:

```
#search all source file name
SOURCES := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -name '*.c')
# Make list of object files with paths
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o))
```

Ok I think that this can work, but now how I can automatically compile all .c file with their dependencies?

Note: I am not that used to makefiles, I know the basics.

Comment: If what you're trying to do is create C or C++ dependency information automatically, there's nothing built into make that will do that for you.  However there are a number of examples of how to do it; you might find this one helpful: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: Look at such commands in Make as: patsubst, notdir, wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Generate a bunch of rules using `foreach`. `CCompilation` below implements the template recipe to be used by `foreach` on every directory being mentioned in `$(SOURCES)`. Note, that the last free line in the recipe is an important delimiter.

```
$(foreach DIRECTORY, $(dir $(SOURCES)), 
          $(call CCompilation, OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, EXTRA_STUFF, $(DIRECTORY)))

define CCompilation 
$(1)/%.o: $(3)/%.c
    CC $< $(2) -o $$@

endef
```